# Maximum of a Function Bounded by Average of Integral and Integral of Derivative

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

> Suppose $f$ is continuous and that $f$ is $C^1$. Prove that $$\max_{x\in[a, b]}|f(x)|\;\leq\; \frac{1}{b-a}\Big|\int_a^b f(x)dx\Big| \,+\, \int_a^b |f'(x)|dx.$$
> (Hint: how are the maximum of $f(x)$ and its average related by the fundamental theorem of calculus?)

Could somebody provide an example proof?

Comment: @bjorn93 in the proof user284331 gave, I saw he wrote $|f(x)|$ - how can we show this for max$|f(x)|?$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$\int_{a}^{b} |f'| \geq \max_{s,t \in [a,b]} \left|\int_{t}^{s} f'\right| =\max_{s,t \in [a,b]} |f(s)-f(t)| \geq \max_{s,t \in [a,b]} |f(s)|-|f(t)| = \max_{s \in [a,b]} |f(s)| - \min_{s \in [a,b]} |f(s)|$$

and $$\frac{1}{b-a} \left|\int_{a}^{b} f\right| = |f(c)|$$ for some $c \in [a,b]$ by the mean value theorem.

The result follows from the fact that $|f(c)| \geq \min_{s \in [a,b]} |f(s)|$.

Comment: @TimBrady is because of [triangular inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality): $|x + y| \leq |x|+|y|$, in its integral form is equivalent to $|\int f dt| \leq \int |f| dt$... so $\sup | \int_s^t f' | \leq \sup \int_s^t |f'|$ and since you are adding now only positive values, given that $[s, t] \subset [a, b]$ it follows that $\sup \int_s^t |f'| \leq \sup \int_a^b |f'|$... with the answer already given the full question is solved.